# Linux Driver for Roland GR-55

Tags: linux, driver

Currently Roland does not make drivers for Linux, so I am starting a project to write a driver for the Roland GR-55 Guitar Synthesizer, but after looking around, I find I have several options and not sure which is the best or most current method, so I thought I'd ask before waisting a lot of time on this.

This device uses USB, it controls the MIDI and Audio devices in the GR-55.

ALSA or libusb api are two choices; both are new to me; its been years since I wrote a device driver and it was for Unix back in the 80's, but I do know I can figure out how, once I know what tools to use, which I'm guessing both use C still; I have looked at the libusb api; very nice; but I have no idea about ALSA project; seems they are geared into getting modules into the kernel to achieve this.

I would like to find programmers that have worked with Roland like Device Drivers dealing with MIDI and Audio that might be able to help point me in the right direction; I have asked Roland for help; will be waiting for a reply, but not wanting to hold my breath, I think getting started would be my best option; even if they do help, they will only be suppling technical specs, which would be great.

I hope I gave enough details; not much else to say when asking a question about Device drivers.

Comment: Hmm. I think you'll be better off asking around music production forums or perhaps writing to people involved in ALSA development. Maybe even http://audio.stackexchange.com/

Comment: A simple search will show I did. [link]http://www.vguitarforums.com/smf/index.php?topic=3854.0

Comment: Maybe I should have asked a generic question about writing a generic USB driver, because I don't think it matters; a driver is a driver.